# Every time I try to return this variable it returns as None

Tags: python

I am trying to use this function to get user input in creating a dict object that I can use to generate a .json file and the function works right up until you type done it does realize that you typed done and
it does display the variable you are creating as its being added on to but when you try to return it it always outputs 'None'. I am using the latest version of python. Me and my teacher have no idea why it doesn't work.

```
def menu_asset_create_lang(lang):

    # The functions "header, space, and br"
    # are all just for making the text look nice in
    # the command line all they do is print stuff for
    # formatting and clear just does os.system('cls')


    clear()
    header()

    print('Lang Creation: ')
    space()
    print(lang)
    br()
    print('< Done')
    inp1 = labeled_input('Input Lang Code')

    if(inp1 == 'done') or (inp1 == '<'):
        return lang

    inp2 = labeled_input('Input Translation')

    lang.append(inp1 + '\":\"' + inp2)


    menu_asset_create_lang(lang)

# instantiate the variable
lang = []

# feed it into the function and make it
# spit out the generated variable in console
print(menu_asset_create_lang(lang))
```

also I have tried doing this:

```
lang = []
langout = menu_asset_create_lang(lang)
print(langout)
```

Also please understand that I am pretty new to python.

Comment: Your function has no `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None` by default

Comment: Your recursive case is missing the return statement. Try changing the last line in the function to `return menu_asset_create_lang(lang)`

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call `menu_asset_create_lang(lang)` is just hanging there: after Python executes it, and after this call returns *anything*, the function body ends, so that `None` will be returned implicitly.

Currently, your code is the same as:

```
def menu_asset_create_lang(lang):
    ...
    menu_asset_create_lang(lang)
    return None
```

Can you see what you should return instead of `None`?

Comment: The function prints the variable each time it repeats so you can actively see it change as you add on to it and it displays the correct information the only problem is getting that variable out of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def menu_asset_create_lang(lang):

    # The functions "header, space, and br"
    # are all just for making the text look nice in
    # the command line all they do is print stuff for
    # formatting and clear just does os.system('cls')


    clear()
    header()

    print('Lang Creation: ')
    space()
    print(lang)
    br()
    print('< Done')
    inp1 = labeled_input('Input Lang Code')

    if(inp1 == 'done') or (inp1 == '<'):
        return lang

    inp2 = labeled_input('Input Translation')

    lang.append(inp1 + '\":\"' + inp2)


    return menu_asset_create_lang(lang)
```

I am hoping you have a recursive return
Python returns `None` by default